# $\Leftrightarrow$ operator in integral probability metrics

Tags: probability-theory

I often see

$$d(P,Q) := \sup_{f \in F} \left| \int f \, \text{d}P \Leftrightarrow \int f \, \text{d}Q \right|$$

in literature integral probability metrics. What is the difference between the notation with $\Leftrightarrow$ and the following?

$$d(P,Q) := \sup_{f \in F} \left| \int f \, \text{d}P - \int f \, \text{d}Q \right|$$

Edit: An example is "A. Müller. Integral probability metrics and their generating classes of functions. Adv. Appl. Prob., 29:429–443, 1997." [PDF](http://digbib.ubka.uni-karlsruhe.de/volltexte/documents/2105)

Comment: Any source for the $\Leftrightarrow$ version? It seems absurd.

Comment: The PDF you link to is a preliminary version of the paper available on the author's website. The [published version](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1428011?uid=3738016&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104166398333) comes back to more standard notations, hence $\Leftrightarrow$ is just a misprint for $-$.